# JSF 2 support in IntelliJ Idea 11

Tags: maven, jsf-2, intellij-idea

I want to use h:link component in my xhtml file but Idea doesn't seem to find it. I get cannot resolve symbol error. But it does find some other standard components.

I have following header at the top of the file.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
```

The project i'm working on is JavaEE6 / JBoss7 type of project. It was imported from Maven archetype. Packaging type is EAR. I have enabled JSF support and Idea has downloaded 3 JSF jars and placed them in lib directory in project root directory (not in web module as i expected).

Does anybody knows what i have to do to make it work?

Comment: First this to exclude the one and other: what if you ignore the IDE error and just run the webapp? Does the `<h:link>` get parsed to a fullworthy `<a>` or not?

Comment: I tried to run app anyway but instead of <a> tag i get a span element.

Comment: Make sure that JSF jars are added to the module dependencies: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: I added jsf jars to maven's pom.xml and now it finally works.

Comment: To help people who are in the same situation later, you may want to post what you did as an answer and mark it accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding jsf jars to Maven's pom.xml.

In my case (note that i'm running this on JBoss7 AS and these jars are already on server)

```
   <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included
    in JBoss AS 7 -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.7</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.7</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Hope it helps.